# Clipboard keeps pasting url source file while pasting text

Tags: clipboard

Hello everyone I have a problem while pasting my text it keeps show the url file source is there any way to disable to show disable the url?

Here is the example :
[Case example](https://freeimage.host/i/JwCmPnt)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your picture is unreadable and I have no idea what you're trying to show. I also don't know your Ubuntu product/release details; but when I copy details that I know can have hidden text (such as from a browser which will display one message but have a hidden URL within it) I just paste first into a simple text editor that can only deal with the text itself (*thus URL gets dropped*)...  For me that's fine with me rarely needing to paste elsewhere, but if I did I'd likely copy from the simple text editor as that is the primary text only & paste into wherever I wanted as URL no longer is there.

Comment: FYI:   My method above means I have two copies in my clipboard at the end of my example; I can highlight the *last* placed there and thus paste only the text message itself; OR if I need the full text (with hidden URL) I can select it first from clipboard manager than paste that version.  Again Ubuntu product/release/desktop can influence what options you have & you provided none for me (*to restrict answer to*)